# Accidentally deleted my test folder in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

As the title says, I accidentally deleted the test folder in my Spring boot application and created a folder named test under the src folder. But now, I can't create java class in the test folder. The IDE does not recognize it as a java class. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Just recreate the test folder. If you are using maven, you can see the standard directory layout [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: What build tool are you using? did you do a mvn clean install after you added the test folder again?

Comment: What IDE are you using? You might have to add the new test directory as a "test" resource in the project setting.

Comment: Thanks to @Chaosfire with standard directory layout I fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `java` in the test directory. If you use IDEA, right-click the `java` and choose `Mark Directory as->Test Resources Root` from the shortcut menu. Put your test classes in the `java`.